# How to check whether input focus is in the minibuffer?

Tags: minibuffer

In order to adjust the behavior of my custom keyboard shortcuts I'd like to determine whether or not the current input focus is within the minibuffer. (The buffer seems to be called something like `*Minibuf-1*`.)

Comment: The echo area is not the same thing as the minibuffer (which is what you really mean here): see [The Echo Area](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Echo-Area.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.

Comment: @NickD You are right. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking to know whether the minibuffer window is selected, and so has the input focus. Use predicate `minibuffer-window-active-p`. `C-h f` says:

> `minibuffer-window-active-p` is a compiled Lisp function in `window.el`.
>
> `(minibuffer-window-active-p WINDOW)`
>
> Return t if `WINDOW` is the currently active minibuffer window.

Comment: That is it! Great, thank you very much :-) !